# Laravel whereHas relationship conditionals not working as expected

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a `Product` model which is connected to a `Variant` model. This variant is then connected to an `Option`.

My query:

```
$query = Product::orderBy($params['orderBy'], $params['sort']);

$query->whereHas('variants.options', function($query) use ($params) {
  $query->where('options.name', '10');
  $query->where('options.name', 'rose');
  $query->where('inventory_quantity', '>', 0);
});
```

For some reason this is not returning the `Products` which have a `Variant` that has two seperate `Options` connected (`10` and `Rose`) and where the variant's `inventory_quantity` is bigger than 0.

It works properly when I remove the `$query->where('options.name', 'rose');` line.

The variants are connected to options via the `variant_option` pivot table. The values are properly stored in that table.

Comment: For a particular record how `options.name` will be both `rose` and 10?

Comment: You can look at it as a 'tag'. They are stored in the `options` table and are connected via the pivot table `variant_option`.

Comment: I think you are supposed to looks for `$query->where('options.name', '10')
          ->orWhere('options.name', 'rose');`

Comment: I tried that but i want to retrieve a combination of those two options, so not OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying products which have an option (through variants) which has a name that is 10 and rose at the same time. Of course that can never be true.

Instead, you need to add two `whereHas()` blocks inside a `whereHas('variants')` block to assert both options:

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->whereHas('variants', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) {
            $query->where('options.name', '10');
        })
        ->whereHas('options', function ($query) {
            $query->where('options.name', 'rose');
        })
        ->where('inventory_quantity', '>', 0);
    })
    ->orderBy($params['orderBy'], $params['sort'])
    ->get();
```

This literally reads as:
Give me all products which have at least one variant that is in stock and has at least two options of which one is named `10` and one is named `rose`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read somewhere this is not necessary since multiple `->where()` calls are also possible. I tried your solution but when i change `rose` to `yellow` it should not return the parent product because that particular Variant has `inventory_quantity` 0. The product however is still being returned. So it should be a combination of '10', 'yellow' and 'inventory_quantity' (not OR).

Comment: That's probably the case because the product has two variants, one with an option named `10` of which the quantity is higher than zero; and another variant with an option named `yellow` of which the quantity is also higher than zero. If you want products which have a quantity that fulfills both requirements, you need to wrap the calls differently. Updating my answer in a sec...

Comment: Sorry if its not the clearest problem description :) So i have one variant who has options `10` and `rose` combined who has inventory_quantity 1 and one variant who has options `10` and `yellow` combined who has inventory_quantity 0.

Comment: On which table is the inventory quantity stored?

Comment: I think it works! Thanks so much :) The inventory_quantity is stored on `variants`.

Comment: Then you should move the `where('inventory_quantity')` part to the outer `whereHas()` as updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
$query->whereHas('variants.options', function($query) use ($params) {
  $query->where(function($q){
    $q->where('options.name', '10');
    $q->orwhere('options.name', 'rose');
  })
  $query->where('inventory_quantity', '>', 0);
});
```